# How can I change the names of objects in a DWFx file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I did a conversion program to change the object structure of a DWFx file, and it works fine. What I did was to open the DWFx file as a zip archive, parse the internal XML files, and reorganize them, creating new parent nodes when needed.

But what doesn't work is changing the names of these nodes. When I open the file in any Autodesk viewer (the offline Design Review program and the online Viewer are the ones I tested), the tree structure is changed as it should, but the parent node names are not. In fact, the nodes that already existed keep their old names, and the new ones are called Object XXXX. The child nodes (actual objects) have their names changed correctly.

I tried to search in every readable (text) file inside the DWFx, but none of them hold any other reference to these nodes. I didn't open binary files, like W3D files, which probably hold the geometry.

Does anyone have any experience in creating or altering DWFx files? Do I need to change anything else besides the 'label' tag in the Presentation XML file?

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything with coding. Did you try other forums?

Comment: No, this is my first attempt at asking, after a week of research. I don't know where such a question would be appropriate, really.  I think Stack Overflow is global enough to reach at least a couple of users who worked inside a dwfx file, so it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating the contents of DWFx files manually, consider using one of the [Autodesk Forge](https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/documentation) services: [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/developers_guide/overview). The APIs allow you to run AutoCAD "in the cloud". You could theoretically load your DWFx file there, update the structure/names, and generate an updated DWFx file. Here's an example of how the service can be used to generate PDFs out of DWG files: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/tutorials/convert-dwg-to-pdf.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'm not into AutoCAD scripting, but I'll ask the engineering team how to do it.
However, I'll let it as a plan B, because, by altering the DWFx structure directly (which is done, except for parent node names), the workflow is not dependent on Autodesk structure. Bad networks, changes to their APIs, subscriptions, etc., won't affect the resulting file. That's why I'm trying to change it on the source directly.